# Django 1.6.5 and 1.5.4 Tango with django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am wanting to go through the [tango with django tutorial](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/) but it is for django 1.5.4. The current version is 1.6.5 is the much difference? Could I learn on 1.5.4 then switch to the newest version with out much trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `Django 1.5.4` that the tutorial was written for. This way you would avoid side effects, deprecation warnings and different kind of surprises.

Then, after getting through the book, look at the [Django 1.6 Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/) to see what is new in Django 1.6 comparing to Django 1.5. The biggest major change in the release is [Improved transaction management](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#improved-transaction-management).

In other words, [the ideas and principles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/) that Django follows are robust and don't change from release to release. This tutorial is a great way to get into the world of *Perfectionists with deadlines*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through it myself at the moment... using Django 1.6.5.

No major worries yet, though some reading-between-the-lines is required.  Some things the tutorial has you do, such as setting up settings.py for dynamic paths appear to be already done by default in 1.6.5, and with very slightly different wording (i.e. BASE_DIR vs. PROJECT_PATH).

So far, heading into chapter 5 thats the 'big' difference I've noticed thus far.  Maybe there will be more to follow.  The end-of-chapter 'exercises' so far have been very useful at helping me to better understand what it is I just did.  Following along with the tutorial is one thing, being able to apply it even in little bits makes a world of difference for me.